# How to use 3rd party JQuery file uploader with SharePoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

The OOTB attaching of files in a share point list is a one by one process. I wanted to create a front end solution which would enable multiple attachment of files at once. I researched a lot and the obvious solution was to use a JQuery based multiple upload plugin. The problem i faced was every 3rd party plugin i found worked on PHP based site where the uploading of file is handled automatically. Is there a way such that we can use the plugin to work with SharePoint List/document library, maybe I can alter the code at the backend of the plugin. Any help or suggestion to achieve this will immensely help.

The plugin I am trying to hook up with SharePoint is [jQuery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Setup)

Thanks for all your help!